# Developing Web Applications on the Mac

Tags: macos

How does one build Web applications on the Mac that is not RoR or PHP? Can Web applications be created using Objective-C and Cocoa? I'm entirely new to this subject

- Hahnemann

Answer (score 9):

Cocoa is really not a web application framework, so I wouldn't recommend you go that route. WebObjects (see KiwiBastard's answer) used to be written in Objective-C but (since version 5, I think) is written in Java.

Because OS X is a UNIX OS, many of the standard web stack will run (in fact, most of it is installed by deafult). So you could write CGI in perl, python, C, or whatever. You can also use JBoss (a Java app server) bundled with OS X Server or any of the other Java web-app stacks.

I'm not sure why you are against RoR and PHP, but you may also want to take a look at some of the python web frameworks [1](http://turbogears.com) such as [TurboGears](http://turbogears.com), [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com), [Zope](http://zope.org), etc.

[1](http://turbogears.com) Python 2.5 is also installed with OS X 10.5

Answer (score 7):

The "Apple" way is to use [WebObjects](http://www.apple.com/webobjects/)

Comment: Not really. Once they ported it to java, it was gone

Comment: Not really, Stephan - it's supported, easy to deploy (thanks to WAR deployment) on a wide variety of platforms, and has significant improvements over the last ObjC version (4.5).

Answer (score 7):

Have a look a [Objective-J and Cappuccino](http://cappuccino.org/), it's basically Cocoa for the Web. You can even use interface builder!(Build your web GUI with Drag and Drop)

Answer (score 4):

I have to recommend Grails:

http://grails.org

If you have experience with cocoa then:

http://cappuccino.org/

Otherwise, stick to an established technology.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your web app to look like an Objective-C and Cocoa app, you could look into [SproutCore](http://www.sproutcore.com/).

It's a Javascript framework, but pretty easy to understand and use.

Answer (score 1):

Is your problem with Rails or Ruby?  If the former, you may want to have a look at [Merb](http://merbivore.com/contribute.html), many interesting links [here](http://www.rubyinside.com/44-merb-resources-1318.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am using Seaside on Squeak (Smalltalk). I daily transfer the code from pc to mac and back again, as it is fully cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using eclipse for java & php projects.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's the problem - ask a hundred people and you get a hundred answers! On the PC, I develop using .NET and Visual Studio, and that's it. I was also hoping for an Apple equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

think thats the problem - ask a hundred people and you get a hundred answers! On the Pc I develop using .NET and Visual Studio - and thats it. I was also hoping for an Apple equivalent. An not something obscure that you can't readily hire programmers for in the market (well here in the UK anyway).